# json call does'nt update in IE 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson

I use this tiny script to feed a playlist and updates it every 20 sec. - for some reason it does'nt update in ie10 (and older versions too, I guess) - I failed to see where it goes wrong, any ideas...?

```
    function playlist() {
    $.getJSON("/playlist/", function (data) {
        $("#play-now-arti").empty();
        $("#play-now-title").empty();
        $("#last-played").empty();
        var i = 0;
        $.each(data.PlayHistory.PlayInfo, function (index, value) {
            var arti = value["ARTI"];
            var title = value["TITLE"];
            i++;
            if (i == 1) {
                $("#now-playing-artist").html(arti);
                $("#now-playing-song").html(title);
            }
            else if (i > 1 && i < 8) {
                $("<li>" + arti + " - <span>" + title + "</span></li>").appendTo("#last-played");
            }
        });
    });
    setTimeout(playlist, 20000);
};
playlist();
```

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with caching? Try sending a unique get request each time, maybe add the current time to the get url.

Comment: I suspect @zaf is probably correct.  IE is horrible for caching stuff sometimes.  You can switch to the underlying [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) method and specify the `cache` parameter as `false`, which will currently be defaulting to `true` for your request, or as suggested by @zaf, append a timestamp yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It was caching, indeed... - by adding "$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });" to my function IE now updates just like the other browsers...

```
function playlist() {
            $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
            $.getJSON("/playlist/", function (data) {
                $("#playlist").empty();
                var i = 0;
                $.each(data.PlayHistory.PlayInfo, function (index, value) {
                    var arti = value["ARTI"];
                    var title = value["TITLE"];
                    var spotify = value["Spotify"];
                    i++;
                    if (i == 1) {
                        $("<li class=\"jp-playlist-current\"><div tabindex=\"0\" class=\"jp-playlist-item jp-playlist-current\"><span class=\"jp-artist\">" + arti + ":</span><a href=\"" + spotify + "\" target=\"_blank\" title=\"Lyt i Spotify\"><img src=\"/img/spotify.png\" style=\"border: 0;\" /></a><br><span class=\"jp-title\">" + title + "</span></div></li>").appendTo("#playlist");
                    }
                    else {
                        $("<li><div tabindex=\"0\" class=\"jp-playlist-item\"><span class=\"jp-artist\">" + arti + ":</span><a href=\"" + spotify + "\" target=\"_blank\" title=\"Lyt i Spotify\"><img src=\"/img/spotify.png\" style=\"border: 0;\" /></a><br><span class=\"jp-title\">" + title + "</span></div></li>").appendTo("#playlist");
                    }
                });
            });
            setTimeout(playlist, 200000);
        };
        playlist();
```